# Gson.toJson() throw StackOverflowError when passing Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gson, stack-overflow, to-json

I'm developing an app and on Android 6 (SDK 23) the code below goes into StackOverflow, but removing the putExtra() works correctly.
Can you help me out?

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Clazz.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", 2);
String json = gson.toJson(intent);
```

Comment: what about other devices?

Comment: @ShaluTD It works properly